# Create divs of different colors through a loop with jinja and js

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2, data-visualization, templating

I'm using jinja and javascript in my template to create several rows of 100 boxes where some of the boxes are one color and some are another, depending on the number in the row of data. For example, if a row in my spreadsheet has the following:

```
year  men  women
1988  60    40
```

that row on my page would be the year, then 60 green boxes (# of men) and 40 yellow boxes (# of men). I'm currently doing this with a jinja loop, but it's only spitting out one row of different-colored boxes.

```
{% for row in years %}

<script>
    var htmlElements = "";
    var container = document.getElementById("boxes");
    for (var i = 0; i < {{ row.men }}; i++) {
        htmlElements += '<div class="men"></div>';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < {{ row.women }}; i++) {
        htmlElements += '<div class="women"></div>';
    }
    container.innerHTML = htmlElements;
</script>

<div class="row box-row">
    <div class="two columns">
        <p id="{{ row.id }}" class="year-text">{{ row.year }}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="boxes" class="ten columns"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="six columns offset-by-five">
        <a href="#" class="scrollToTop">Jump To Top</a>
    </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

This code produces all the years on the page, but only the *first* row of different-colored boxes. I've checked to make sure the header row of my data matches what I have in the script tag above. I'm not sure if I'm using the jinja variables correctly in my script. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Any reason why you aren't doing the entire thing in Jinja HTML tags? Is the js necessary?

Comment: I have no idea how to translate the js code into Jinja and fulfill the same requirements (of specific numbers of divs). I would def prefer to do it all in Jinja if that's doable. Any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do it all in jinja.  You may need to tweak this a bit to make it work with the code that you haven't posted, but here is what I came up with:

```
{% for row in years %}

    <div class="container">
    {% for male_boxes in row.men %}
        <div class="men"></div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for female_boxes in row.women %}
        <div class="women"></div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div class="row box-row">
        <div class="two columns">
            <p id="{{ row.id }}" class="year-text">{{ row.year }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="boxes" class="ten columns"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="six columns offset-by-five">
            <a href="#" class="scrollToTop">Jump To Top</a>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Note: I changed one of your `<div>` `id`s to a `class`, because you were creating it inside the loop, which would create multiple elements with an `id`, and that won't work in HTML.  Watch out for those.

Comment: Tried this, and I was getting a "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" so I added "range" into it (i.e. `{% for male_boxes in range(row.men) %}` which made the page pop up, but no boxes :(  No errors in the console and I inspected it -- the boxes aren't there. I'm not sure why it doesn't see `row.men` as iterable.

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help.  If this answer was useful for you, then I'd like to encourage you to mark it as the accepted answer for this question.

Comment: For others, the above worked by making `{% for male_boxes in row.men %}` and `{% for female_boxes in row.women %}` into `{% for male_boxes in range(row.men) %}` and `{% for female_boxes in range(row.women) %}`, respectively.